# In a Plotly timeline Gantt chart, how to have each y-axis category ("task") in a new line, even for repeating tasks?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

The default code ([taken from the Plotly Gantt chart intro](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/)) has each repeating tasks added to the same horizontal line in the figure. For example, the code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource='Alex'),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource='Max'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource='Max'),
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-03-02', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource='Alex')
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color = "Resource")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

Produces :
[image]

And I would like to have each tasks in the input data frame into its own line in the y-axis, even for repeating tasks :
[image]

(To obtain this figure, I created a new "Task A." in the df, adding a dot at the end to force a new horizontal line next to "Task A" without dot).

I tried different arguments for `fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder = "")` to no avail.

Any help is appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, the graphs are created in units of categorical variables for job and person names, so I think the only approach you have adopted is the one you have used.

Comment: Hi. I did not understand your comment, specially your last sentence. Do you mean there is no way to do what I want ? could we play with the categorical variables used inside the figure creating somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:  `y=df.groupby(["Start"])["Task"]`?

**Edit:**
I think you can find how to change the ticklabels here [Plotly - Yaxis documentation](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/docs/plotly.graph_objs.layout.YAxis)

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource='Alex'),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource='Max'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource='Max'),
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-03-02', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource='Alex')
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y=df.groupby(["Start"])["Task"], color = "Resource")
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title="Task",  autorange="reversed"))
fig.show()
```

[image: The four bar]

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your time. I tried `fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y=df.groupby(["Start"])["Task"], color="Resource")` with the given `df`. This produced a very weird graph: [see here](https://ibb.co/Wpx55M6). Did you mean to use it this way ?

Comment: The tickslabels are awful, I grant you that.

Comment: I tried this, but in the layout y-axis documentation I could not find a way to set the labels in the correct order and value (playing again with `categoryarray` and `categoryorder`)